# Assign same static IP to a Windows 2003 VPN client connection

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2003-r2

Every time a domain user is using our Windows VPN to connect to the company network a new IP from a range is taken. This range is configured in a Windows 2003 Server. Because we have applications that require static IP (same IP every time the domain user connects through the VPN) how can we achieve this? I have already found a youtube video https://youtu.be/5ZuEkZJak5E says to go to the active directory and check the "Assign static IP address" on the user's dial-in tab properties. But this is gray-out and I can't change it. I found that this is because the Domain Functional Level is "Windows 2000" and must be raised to "Windows 2003". But the server is old and If there will be any problem then there will be no return. So I would like to confirm if this is the way so I don't bother again or if not then suggest something else.

Comment: Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault. 2003 is dead.. Dead.. Dead, and EOL ages ago.... ;) I mean any practice attack csn wipe your entire network with no time to respond due the lack of updates

Comment: Probably - but as you mention you're running an unsupported configuration, and you should rectify that first and foremost, and second attempt to add features.

Comment: You have mentioned two totally different things. "Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices". What you have not understood. The question is very clear. About the second (unsupported platform) you have right. But there is already a tag with Windows-2003-r2 in Server-Fault!!! And anyway, you don't have to get involved if you're not interested. Repeated clichés like I need to upgrade are not serious. Of course I know it and it's obvious. Only a very stupid person would not understand that. So obviously there is some reason that is not known to the rest.